# Validate Foreign Keys, just one to have a not null value

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with 2 FK keys

```
class C(models.Model):
    a1 = models.ForeignKey(A, blank=True, null=True, related_name='c', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    a2 = models.ForeignKey(B, blank=True, null=True, related_name='c', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When the model is saved I want just on FK to exist, the other to be null. If is not this case o raise a Validation.

Because I need it also in Django Admin, I prefer to be done in the Model, to avoid using a complex custom form in Django Admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method for your model.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class C(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.a1_id and self.a2_id:
            raise ValidationError("You can only select one")
        elif not (self.a1_id or self.a2_id):
            raise ValidationError("You must select one")
```